Suppress PowerShell prompts when executing script from standard input
Let's say that I have a script with multiple PowerShell commands I want to run on a remote computer, for example:
PS C:\path\to\script> Get-Content example.ps1
Write-Output "$Env:USERNAME"
Write-Output "$Env:COMPUTERNAME"

(In reality I am constructing the list of commands dynamically.) I can execute this script on the remote by running PowerShell and reading the script from standard input:
PS C:\path\to\script> Get-Content example.ps1 | ssh server 'powershell -File -'
PS C:\Users\rcampion> Write-Output "$Env:USERNAME"
rcampion
PS C:\Users\rcampion> Write-Output "$Env:COMPUTERNAME"
SERVER
PS C:\Users\rcampion>
PS C:\path\to\script>

However, you can see that in addition to the output from the script, PowerShell is printing prompts and echoing the commands, which makes parsing the output more difficult. This behavior seems to be a special case of the -File option:

If the value of File is -, then commands are read from standard input. Running powershell -File - without redirected standard input starts a regular session. This is the same as not specifying the File parameter at all. When reading from standard input, the input statements are executed one statement at a time as though they were typed at the PowerShell command prompt.
about_PowerShell_exe

Things I have tried:

Using the -NonInteractive option has no effect.
Piping the input through another command (e.g. findstr ".*" | powershell -File -) has no effect (doesn't count as 'redirected' standard input I guess?).
Redirecting standard input to itself (powershell -File <&0) results in an error (The handle could not be duplicated during redirection of handle 0.)
Using -Command "Invoke-Expression $input"; this actually gets a little closer, but doesn't properly execute more than one command. With the above script I get the output:
rcampion
Write-Output
SERVER
PS C:\path\to\script>

The only command executing is the first Write-Output, the second is being treated as an argument which is why it gets printed out too.

Is there any way to either tell PowerShell to not output the prompts or to trick it into thinking the input is redirected?

(For me) makesomecommands | powershell -command - does not prompt or echo and handles single-line, and multi-line using & { ... } or invoke-command similarly, and sometimes but not always (!) backtick continuation

@dave_thompson_085 Wow, I can't believe I didn't try that! Seems like whether backtick continuation works depends on the number of blank lines occuring later in the file, something to do with being parsed "as though they were typed at the PowerShell command prompt" I would guess... this requires some more experimentation

Here is my current hacky workaround using Invoke-Expression:
powershell -Command '$input | ForEach-Object { Invoke-Expression $_ }'

In action:
PS C:\path\to\script> Get-Content example.ps1 | ssh server 'powershell -Command \"$input | ForEach-Object { Invoke-Expression $_ }\"'
rcampion
SERVER
PS C:\path\to\script>

However, it executes each line as a separate command, so if you have any multiline commands they will fail:
PS C:\path\to\script> Get-Content example.ps1
Write-Output "$Env:USERNAME"
Write-Output `
    "$Env:COMPUTERNAME"
PS C:\Users\rbcampio\Documents\RST\STOP\stop-pipeline-automation> .\example.ps1
rcampion
LOCAL
PS C:\Users\rbcampio\Documents\RST\STOP\stop-pipeline-automation> Get-Content example.ps1 | ssh server 'powershell -Command \"$input | ForEach-Object { Invoke-Expression $_ }\"'
rcampion
Invoke-Expression : At line:1 char:16
+ Write-Output `
+                ~
Incomplete string token.
At line:1 char:27
+ $input | ForEach-Object { Invoke-Expression $_ }
+                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [Invoke-Expression], ParseException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : IncompleteString,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeExpressionCommand

SERVER
PS C:\Users\rbcampio\Documents\RST\STOP\stop-pipeline-automation>

I'm still looking for a better solution if anyone has one.
